# After angular 14 upgrade - codeCoverage unknown parameter error

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

After upgrading from angular 13 to 14, the command `ng test angular-uicomp-lib --codeCoverage=true`(where angular-uicomp-lib is folder name to be tested) is failing.
Getting following error: **Error: Unknown argument: codeCoverage**

Need to know what can be done such that the command executes successfully. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

You must now use --code-coverage instead of codeCoverage

```
Options:
      --help                   Shows a help message for this command in the console.                                                                       [boolean]
  -c, --configuration          One or more named builder configurations as a comma-separated list as specified in the "configurations" section in angular.json.     
                               The builder uses the named configurations to run the given target.
                               For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations.                          [string]
      --browsers               Override which browsers tests are run against.                                                                               [string]
      --code-coverage          Output a code coverage report.                                                                             [boolean] [default: false]
      --code-coverage-exclude  Globs to exclude from code coverage.                                                                                          [array]
      --include                Globs of files to include, relative to workspace or project root.
                               There are 2 special cases:
                               - when a path to directory is provided, all spec files ending ".spec.@(ts|tsx)" will be included
                               - when a path to a file is provided, and a matching spec file exists it will be included instead.                             [array]
      --inline-style-language  The stylesheet language to use for the application's inline component styles.
                                                                                                  [string] [choices: "css", "less", "sass", "scss"] [default: "css"]
      --karma-config           The name of the Karma configuration file.                                                                                    [string]
      --main                   The name of the main entry-point file.                                                                                       [string]
      --poll                   Enable and define the file watching poll time period in milliseconds.                                                        [number]
      --polyfills              The name of the polyfills file.                                                                                              [string]
      --preserve-symlinks      Do not use the real path when resolving modules. If unset then will default to `true` if NodeJS option --preserve-symlinks is set.   
                                                                                                                                                           [boolean]
      --progress               Log progress to the console while building.                                                                 [boolean] [default: true]
      --reporters              Karma reporters to use. Directly passed to the karma runner.                                                                  [array]
      --source-map             Output source maps for scripts and styles. For more information, see
                               https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration.                                         [boolean] [default: true]
      --ts-config              The name of the TypeScript configuration file.                                                                               [string]
      --watch                  Run build when files change.                                                                                                [boolean]
      --web-worker-ts-config   TypeScript configuration for Web Worker modules.                                                                             [string]
```

Answer (score 1):

The current correct option seems to be --coverage, not --code-coverage.
Weirdly it is not mentioned in the help (Angular 14.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Add coverage-istanbul to your reporters.
For example:

```
 reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul'],
```